# choosing where to save sqlite database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

This is probably a simple question, but I could use some help. I am trying to build a small database for an application that will only be run on my computer so I want to create a local database.

To do this I am trying to use sqlite. I can use the command prompt to make what seems to be a database by using the sqlite3 databaseName; functionality, but I do not know where it is being stored.

I need to be able to find the database to access it through the application I am experimenting with. I already know all of the basic sql and such for creating the database tables and data, but I cannot figure out how to simply make the database connection.

is there a way to specify where the database .db file will be stored, and why can I not find the file it seems to be making?

Comment: The filename specified in the *connect* is where the database file will be create/stored. Normally (e.g. without additional path information) this will be relative to the Current Working Directory which is normally appropriate. If you wish the database file to be created elsewhere (such as in Local Data, perhaps), specify the (full) appropriate path. Any relevant directories must already exist.

Comment: Have the same problem. No file is created. What additional commands must be issued for the file to be actually written to disk?

Comment: Few min later .. was able to get it working by running "sqlite3.exe" to create in-memory DB, then typing ".save mydb.db" at the prompt. This was the only way I could get the file on disk. Executing "sqlite3.exe mydb.db" started sqlite, appearing to create the DB, but did not write the file to disk.

Answer (score 6):

Using sqlite3 shell? Some help using `sqlite3 -help`:

> Usage: sqlite3 [OPTIONS] FILENAME [SQL]

If `FILENAME` is not supplied, shell uses an temporary database.

If you start shell without supplying a filename, you may save temporary database at any time using:

```
sqlite> .backup MAIN "folder\your_file.extension"
```

Or you can `ATTACH` an existing database an use SQL methods:

```
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE "path\stored.db" AS other;
sqlite> INSERT OR REPLACE INTO other.table1 SELECT * FROM this_table1;
sqlite> DETACH other;
```

Comment: Without a file name, you do not get an in-memory database but a temporary database.

Answer (score 0):

For doing such things , you can use Sqlite Manager , you'll get it as a Firefox addon. It's excellent in creating / Managing Sqlite database.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Comment: After extensive use of Sqlite management tools including the above, I'd suggest http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Database-Utils/SQLiteStudio.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for answering, but it turns out my issue was much simpler than I thought.

I was trying to name the database after already starting the shell.

I was supposed to create the database from command line by doing sqlite3 name.db

But I was trying to use that command within the sqlite shell so nothing was being created.